# Flutter ListView.builder not updating if the childrens are widgets

Tags: list, flutter, dart

The basic idea is that I have this list of items which are of the type Person:

```
class Person {
   int height;
   String name;

}
```

By pressing a button I order this list based on the height or name of the person and then call setState() {} to rebuild the UI.

I also have a `ListView.builder()` displaying each item using a `Text()` like this: `Text(_persons[index].name)`.

Then I went along and created a custom stateful widget, let's say a PersonDisplay() where I pass the person object which gets displayed in a Text() widget and used that to display Persons in the `ListView.builder`

The problem is that if I do so, `_persons` lists gets ordered, but the `ListView.builder` items stays the same order. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: could you add the code you are using ?

Comment: From experience , such problems of lists not reordered is that you need to use keys so that the widget tree can reorder the state objects also not only the stateful classes ,please provide your code .

Comment: I found the issue thanks to your comment! Should I add the code anyway?